# Using mixture of IF ELSE and OR in an SQL CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just want to confirm, if this is the correct way in using IF ELSE OR statement in SQL?

```
CASE DB_NAME() WHEN 'dbName' THEN 'value1' ELSE 'value2-a' OR 'value2-b'
```

Basically i want to make a statement where if the dbName is correct, then it will take value1, else it will take either value2-a or value2-b.

I want to implement this statement in my stored procedure.

Comment: Under what circumstances will it take 'value2-a' or 'value2-b'?

Comment: It will be based on dbName. If say dbName is A, then it will take value1, otherwise it will take value2-a or value2- b.

Comment: Yes, but how will you determine if it's value2-a or value2-b?

Comment: How do you choose between 'value2-a' and 'value2-b'?

Comment: From the exec statement that the user will execute. The exec statement will request with either value2-a or value2-b. Something like this --> exec tableName 'value',''

Comment: Basically the dbName is the environment the db belongs to. So say if the environment is PROD, then it will go for value1, otherwise if its not PROD (either DEV or ITG), then it can accept 2 values, which are value2-a or value2-b. There's no exact requirement as to how to determine whether it picks value2-a or value2-b, it will accept both values and return the result appropriately.

Comment: No, your statement does not make sense, in particular the `or` .  Please describe what you want to do, sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Comment: My situation is simple. If its PROD, it will use value1, otherwise if its not PROD, then it will accept either value2-a or value2-b. The value is all depend on user input anyway, and the statement should be able to process if user execute a statement with value value1 or value2-a or value2-b. If its not these 3 values, then it will return nothing.

Comment: Your situation is simple, and you already have an answer for valid syntax.  To be exact, no, case can not do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not have an if else or option. Each item in a select statement needs to evaluate to one value. You can't get two unique values for one field.

If you want to have multiple options in a CASE WHEN statement you can reuse the WHEN keyword.

For Example

```
         SELECT CASE WHEN DB_NAME() = 'PROD' THEN value1
              WHEN DB_NAME() = 'DEV' THEN value2-a
              ELSE value2-b END DbValue
```

Comment: Isn' this implying that value2-b is applicable if its not PROD or DEV then? I want both value2-a and value2-b to be applicable if its not PROD.

Comment: You can use two case statements, but you can't return both value2a and value2b with one statement.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of `CASE`s, simple and searched. You can use both together. When a `CASE` without the optional `ELSE` falls through it returns `NULL`. Try something like this:

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE
    CASE DB_NAME() -- simple case
        WHEN 'dbName' THEN
            CASE value WHEN 'value1' THEN 1 END -- simple case
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN value IN ('value2-a', 'value2-b') THEN 2 END  -- searched case
    END IS NOT NULL
```

or this:

```
SELECT
    CASE DB_NAME() -- simple case
        WHEN 'dbName' THEN
            CASE value WHEN 'value1' THEN value END -- simple case
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN value IN ('value2-a', 'value2-b') THEN value END  -- searched case
    END AS value
FROM...
```

There is more on `CASE` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Comment: That second solution works for me. Didn't think that you can perform checking on the defined value as well to determine what value to get. I was thinking on how to get it from the dbName point of view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want logic like this:

```
WHERE (db_name() = 'prod' and value = 'value1') OR
      (db_name() <> 'prod' and value in ('value2-a', 'value2-b'))
```

Comment: Can't we use CASE for this?

Comment: @FredA . . . You *can*.  I don't advise it, because `case` inhibits the optimizer and many people find it harder to follow.